# Using pure CSS to style pie-chart of highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I would like to style the highcharts pie-chart using pure CSS.

I can do that with JavaScript but is it possible to do that with pure CSS?

I am with the latest highcharts 9.2.2

[image]

Update:

Thanks for the answer but after a lot of time reading their docs, I still couldn't find ways to modify these two text:

1. The title of the chart.
2. The labels.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can style the chart using CSS by setting styledMode to true.

API references:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.styledMode

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L0pv7bfj/

```
chart: {
 styledMode: true,
 type: 'pie'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would you mind taking a look at my updated question?

Comment: Sure, I've prepared a demo that shows the way to style the title of the chart and the labels. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y12o0dps/